# Deleting field causes list error on all 2sxc modules

Tags: 2sxc

I was in the process of deleting and renaming few fields in the data portion of Content. I received a service error dialog that something was disrupted (sorry did not grab a screenshot).

Going back to view any page with a 2sxc module throws an error, even if the page did not contain that content type that was edited.

Not sure how to troubleshoot and I do not have a very recent backup.

```
Error getting List of Stream. Stream Name: Default DataSource Name: EntityTypeFilter
at ToSic.Eav.DataSources.DataStream.get_LightList() in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.DataSources\DataStream.cs:line 156
   at ToSic.Eav.DataSources.DataStream.get_List() in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.DataSources\DataStream.cs:line 82
   at ToSic.SexyContent.ContentGroupManager.GetContentGroup(Guid contentGroupGuid) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\ContentGroupManager.cs:line 42
   at ToSic.SexyContent.ContentGroupManager.GetContentGroupOrGeneratePreview(Guid groupGuid, Guid previewTemplateGuid) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\ContentGroupManager.cs:line 142
   at ToSic.SexyContent.ContentGroupManager.GetContentGroupForModule(Int32 moduleId) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\ContentGroupManager.cs:line 136
   at ToSic.SexyContent.ContentBlock.ModuleContentBlock..ctor(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, IEnumerable`1 overrideParams) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\ContentBlock\ModuleContentBlock.cs:line 49
   at ToSic.SexyContent.View.get_UserMayEditThisModule() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\View.ascx.cs:line 90
   at ToSic.SexyContent.View.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\View.ascx.cs:line 30
```

Comment: Should mention 2sxc version 8.4.5

Answer (score 0):

This was later handled in a github issue https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/894 and fixed there, but it's an open bug which will be corrected soon.